# Jquery multiselect autocomplete trigger

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, multi-select

Am using

http://wilker-dev.com/jquery-multiselect/ autocomplete plugin.

I want to trigger add event of this plugin onclick of checkboxes with the values.

how can i do it?

Here's my code

```
$('.sampleCats').live('click',function(){
    var catName = $(this).data('name');
    var searchCatData = $("#searchCat").val();
    var ele = '<a class="bit bit-box" data-name="'+catName+'">'+catName+'<a class="closebutton"></a></a>';
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $("#searchCatBox .jquery-multiselect").prepend(ele);
        if(searchCatData)
        {
            $("#searchCat").val(searchCatData+','+catName);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#searchCat").val(catName);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        searchCatData = searchCatData.split(',');
                    $("#searchCat").val(searchCatData.join(','));
        $("#searchCatBox .jquery-multiselect").find("a.bit-box").each(function() {
            if ($(this).data("name") === catName) {
                return $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Its adding the data except the close link and its adding and removing on check and uncheck of checkbox ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try workaround like

```
   $(".checkboxClss").click(function(){
      var htmlToAdd = '<a class="bit bit-box">'+this.value+'<a class="closebutton"></a></a>';
      $('.jquery-multiselect').append(htmlToAdd);
    });
```

When you add any element, this plugin adds new anchor element to a div with class `jquery-multiselect` so instead of manually firing add event you can do the same.
**PS:** I never used this plugin so just checked source code and come up with this workaround, use only if you didnt get any other appropriate solution.

When I check the source code

```
close = $(document.createElement("a"));
        close.addClass("closebutton");
        close.click(__bind(function() {
          return this.remove(a.data("value"));
        }, this));
        a.append(close);
```

just play around and see if you can bind this manually.

Comment: thanks ... i have already tried this method and its appending the data but not the closebutton to clear it ...

Comment: @Arul: I have also added anchor for `closebutton`. May be give a try and let us know

Comment: @karan : added my code to my question ... closebutton class is not applied to the data appended ...

Comment: @Arul: the class is applied. I believe that the as we are adding it dynamically so its not working. Lack of `.on()` method on function which displays close button.

Comment: May be, but i compared the HTML of plugin added by autosuggest and what am appending, its below : 

Appended by Me : 
   <a class="bit bit-box" data-name="Movies">Movies</a>
   <a class="closebutton"></a>
Appended by plugin : 
<a class="bit bit-box" data-name="Movies">Movies <a class="closebutton"></a></a>

Comment: @Arul: Still it wont work, check my updated answer. I have added relevant code there